# prove the greatest lower bound for all positive rational numbers is $0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, real-numbers

**Conclusion : This question makes no sense unless we consider it in the set of real numbers**

---

How to prove the greatest lower bound for all positive rational numbers is $0$?

I can only figure out the following right now:

(1). $0$ is a lower bound for all positive rational numbers;

(2). Any positive rational number is not the greatest lower bound for all positive rational numbers;

Density property of rational numbers may be helpful to prove the conclusion, but  it is not easy for me to give a complete rigorous proof right now.

---

I think

1). There is no guarantee that the greatest lower bound in the question must be a rational number .

2).The question doesn't want to prove that zero is the greatest lower bound in Q, I don't need the proof that 0 is the greatest **rational** lower bound.

Comment: How do you define positive?

Comment: @Dando18 greater than $0$

Comment: Then let $L$ be any lower bound of $\mathbb Q$. You just need to show that $L<0$ for all $L$.

Comment: What sort of proof are you looking for?  Would it suffice to exhibit a sequence of positive rationals that goes to $0$?

Comment: @lulu Better to prove it without using limit

Comment: @iMath `I think there is no guarantee that the greatest lower bound in the question must be a rational number . ` Have a look at my answer.

Comment: Given your edit, I think the line '**Assuming all numbers you know are rational numbers**' is inappropriate and misleading?

Comment: @Shuri2060 Thanks for your warning , I updated the post again

Comment: The basic properties of rational numbers (usually taught to 12 year olds) is sufficient to prove the claim. The only ingredient needed is the definition of grratest lower bound of a subset of rationals. Not every set of rationals bounded below has a greatest lower bound, but some sets (like the set of positive rationals) do have it.

Answer (score 4):

Argue by contradiction.  Suppose $c\in\Bbb Q$ satisfies $c>0$ and $c$ is a lower bound for all rational numbers.  Then $c/2\in\Bbb Q$ and $c/2<c$ since if $c/2\geq c$ then $1/2\geq1$.  A contradiction.

Thus the greatest lower bound must be less or equal to zero.  Now zero is the largest number in that range and zero works so it must be the greatest lower bound.

Comment: Why is it obvious that the lower bound is rational?

Comment: I thought we were looking for the greatest lower bound in $\Bbb Q$.  Is that not the question?

Comment: But a priori we only know that the greatest lower bound exists in $\mathbb R$ (or some completion).  If my set was $\{x\in \mathbb Q \,|\,x>\sqrt 2\}$ then no greatest lower bound would exist (in $\mathbb Q$).

Comment: The "greatest lower bound" for a set is not necessarily in that set- just as "0" is not a **positive** rational number.  For example, the "greatest lower bound" of the set of all rational numbers whose square is larger than 2 is $\sqrt{2}$, not a rational number.

Comment: @lulu Right.  So, for an arbitrary set of rationals, we might "not have a greatest lower bound", in the language of this question.  The set of positive rationals, however, does have a rational greatest lower bound.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  Agreed, but that is what the OP is asking.  If we assume it from the start, there isn;t much of a question.

Comment: @lulu what do you think that we're assuming from the start?

Comment: @lulu It is clear that $0$ is a lower bound.  Moreover, this answer proves that $0$ is the greatest rational lower bound.  What more do you want?

Comment: In this solution, @GregoryGrant is assuming that there is a rational greatest lower bound $c$ (he then shows that $c$ must be $0$).  But a priori $c$ might not exist.

Comment: @lulu he makes no such assumption.  He says *suppose $c$ is a lower bound* (which is greater than $0$), not *suppose that $c$ is the greatest lower bound*.

Comment: I appealed directly to the definition of greatest lower bound in a field, in this case $\Bbb Q$.  The question was not to show the set of positive rationals has a greatest lower bound and that it is in $\Bbb Q$, the question was to show that zero is the greatest lower bound in $\Bbb Q$.  I showed that zero is a lower bound in $\Bbb Q$ and I showed that nothing in $\Bbb Q$ greater than it is a lower bound.  That's the definition of greatest lower bound.  It was implicit in the question that the greatest lower bound exists.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  Well, I can do the same thing with my $\sqrt 2$ example.  That is, if you tell me that $c$ is a rational number greater than $\sqrt 2$ then I can find you another rational  between $c$ and $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant  Ah, that's where we disagree.  If I want to argue, via contradiction, that some value is non-zero then I have two ways to proceed.  I can argue that it exists but is not $0$, or I can argue that it does not exist.  Your argument entirely handles the first case.

Comment: @lulu Right.  In other words, every lower bound to your set satisfies $c^2 \leq 2$.  Since there is no greatest such element in the rationals, there is no greatest lower bound in the rationals.

Comment: @lulu The question is "prove that $0$ is the greatest lower bound".  To start, we prove that $0$ is a lower bound.  Then, we prove (by contradiction) that any other lower bound is at most $0$.  How does this proof fail?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  My point was that arguing that given a $c$ in my set I can always find a $c_1$ between it and the putative lower bound does not imply that the putative lower bound is actual.  I think at some point one has to argue that the sequence $c_i$ we produce goes to $0$ and then invoke the existence of a g.l.b. in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @lulu I proved first that every GLB in $\Bbb Q$ for the positive  rationals must be less or equal to zero.  Then I showed zero is an LB.  Therefore zero is the greatest lower bound.  That argument seems water tight to me.

Comment: Ok, perhaps I am just splitting hairs.  In any case, I'll drop my objection.

Comment: @lulu I just updated my answer. I think that should clarify things.

Comment: Sorry for the vague description of my question.
1). The question doesn't want to prove that zero is the greatest lower bound in Q, so you just proved that 0 is the greatest rational lower bound. 2) I don't mean the greatest lower bound in the question must be a rational number .

Answer (score 1):

Since there has been a discussion below the other answer, I will elaborate a bit more.

The hint still is:
 Use contradiction. And don't read further if you don't want to get spoilered.

---

First I want to note that having a "lower/upper bound" of a set $M$ does not make any sense if it is not refered to a superset $N$ of $M$. 
(Note: $M$ is also a superset of itself, so $N=M$ isn't a problem at all.)

So the definition for (greatest) lower bound is:

- A lower bound of the subset $M$ of $N$ is an element $n∈N$, such that $n≤m$ for all $m∈M$.
- The greatest lower bound (or infimum) of $M$ is a lower bound $n_{inf}∈N$, if for all lower bounds $n'$ it holds $n'≤n_{inf}$.

Therefore the question of OP is clear:

> Assuming all numbers you know are rational numbers, [...]

We only now rational numbers $ℚ$. Hence, we have to proof $0$ is the infimum of $ℚ^+(=M)$ with respect to $ℚ(=N)$.

Then the proof is:

1. $0$ is a lower bound.
2. Assume there is another lower bound $q∈ℚ$ that is larger than $0$. That would mean, that then $0$ would not be the infimum. 
   But since $q>0$ the number $q':=\frac{q}{2}∈ℚ^+$ fulfils  $0<q'<q$. Hence, $q$ is *not* a lower bound, and therefore $0$ must be the infimum of $ℚ^+$

Comment: I have some doubt on your statement that *having a "lower/upper bound" of a set $M$ does not make any sense if it is not refered to a superset $N$ of $M$.*, what about saying 1 is a lower bound  in $\{x\in \mathbb Q \,|\,x<\sqrt 2\}$  for  $\{x\in \mathbb Q \,|\,x>\sqrt 2\}$? here I  have not mentioned the superset of  $\{x\in \mathbb Q \,|\,x>\sqrt 2\}$

Comment: @iMath Your comment is a good example, why my statement *[...] does not make any sense[...]* is "correct". You need a superset ($ℚ$) of both $M_1=\{x∈ℚ|x<√2\}$ and $M_2=\{x∈ℚ|x>√2\}$ with a relation "$≤$" to define that $1$ is a lower bound of $M_2$. Otherwise how is $$1≤x$$ for $x∈M_2$ well-defined?

Answer (score 0):

The greatest lower bound (ie. infimum) $I$ is characterized by two things: 1) $\forall x \in \mathbb{Q}_+: I \leqslant x$, and 2) there exists a sequence of positive rationals that converges to $I$. The last condition is satisfied by eg. $\lbrace 1/n \rbrace_{n=1}^\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that we are "living in a rational world", and consider the set $P$ of strictly positive rationals. Does this set have a greatest lower bound in ${\mathbb Q}$?

Denote the set of lower bounds of $P$ by $L$. Then $0\in L$, but $P\cap L$ is empty: If $c\in P$ then ${c\over2}\in P$ as well. Since ${c\over2}<c$ we may conclude that $c\notin L$.

It follows that $L\subset{\mathbb Q}_{\leq0}\,$, hence $0$ is obviously the maximal element of $L$.